# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Carousel not working aka Why are slides in the same line as the navigation?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have a problem with bootstrap carousel. The slides i made are displayed in the same line as the left and right button. Here's the picture:

[image: carousel error]

And here's the code (it's a copy of bootstrap documentation):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <p>test1</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>First slide label</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                    <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                    <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!--<img style="max-width:100%; height:auto;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" src="people.png" />-->
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLyb7/

Tested in Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m. Same thing in Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: I guess you are missing the bootstrap-carousel.css?

Comment: Does that even exist? I didnt find any docs about this in 3.1.1

Comment: It did in bootstrap 2, but I don't know for sure :)

Comment: Nope, I guess it doesn't exist in 3.1.1. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLyb7/

Comment: If you just add some more content you'll see that the carousel behaves more as you would expect with the left/right icons displaying vertically centered. http://jsfiddle.net/WLyb7/1/

Comment: So if i have a small info to show i cant use Bootstrap carousel, the only hack i guess is to put an empty transparent pic inside and then center the div. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel was originally designed for images with the left and right buttons overlaying the images. (Look at the [example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)). If you don't want to use images, you'll need to add some margin to the items:

```
.carousel .item {
  margin: 0 15%; // 15% is the width of the buttons. Increase it if needed.
}
```

EDIT: Another possibilty would be to simply make the inner DIV holding the slides smaller:

```
.carousel-inner {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto; // for centering.
}
```

Keep in mind, Bootstrap is just a basic framework and its JavaScript is designed to work independently from the layout. You can mostly redesign the carousel anyway you like, for example move the controls (buttons, indicatiors, etc.) anywhere else, or just leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

So the only hack that I know of is to put an empty transparent pic inside the carousel and then display whatever you want inside.